# MySQL: select first element of a comma-separated list

Tags: mysql, sql, split

Unfortunately, I have a field column which contains values like

- 4
- 12,3
- 8,5,6,7

I'm going to write a SELECT statement, whose result would be:

- 4
- 12
- 8

How can I do it in practice, since MySQL does not provide a "split" function?

Comment: Regex?? Did you try using Regex

Answer (score 35, accepted):

Use MySQL's [`SUBSTRING_INDEX`](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/en/string-functions.html#function_substring-index) function:

```
SELECT SUBSTRING_INDEX(field, ',', 1)
```

However, keeping lists in delimiter-separated strings is generally an inefficient use of a relational database management system like MySQL: it is often better to [normalise](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Database_normalization) your data structure by keeping such lists in a separate table of `(id, value)` pairs.

Answer (score 6):

You can use MySQL function [SUBSTRING_INDEX(str,delim,count)](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/string-functions.html#function_substring-index)

```
SELECT SUBSTRING_INDEX(value,',',1) As value FROM ...
```