# Retrieving first name in a string of full names through sql

Tags: mysql, regex

I currently have a column in my mysql DB that stores multiple full names separated by a comma as a string. I need to retrieve only the first name of all the names.

```
names
-------
happy sing, rahul bedi, ashish singh, venkat rao
```

expected output

```
fname
--------
happy
rahul
ashish
venkat
```

number of names will be varied, but all will have a comma as a separator

I have attempted the following but that should only give me the first name:

```
SELECT LEFT(YourColumn, charindex(' ', YourColumn) - 1)
```

Comment: Relevant and obligatory reading on the subject of names: https://www.kalzumeus.com/2010/06/17/falsehoods-programmers-believe-about-names/

Comment: Some things are better done in your app language.  I think it takes 2 lines of PHP with `preg_match_all`.

Answer (score 1):

Use MySQL's [SUBSTRING_INDEX](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/en/string-functions.html#function_substring-index) function:

```
SELECT SUBSTRING_INDEX(field, ',', 1)
```

However, keeping lists in delimiter-separated strings is generally an inefficient use of a relational database management system like MySQL: it is often better to [normalise](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Database_normalization) your data structure by keeping such lists in a separate table of (id, value) pairs.

[source](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11241492/mysql-select-first-element-of-a-comma-separated-list#answer-11241563)

Answer (score 1):

In mysql 8.x You can use [JSON_TABLE](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/json-table-functions.html), to split the row and [SUBSTRING_INDEX](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/string-functions.html#function_substring-index) to get the first name

> ```
> Create TABLE test (names varchar(255));
> ```
>
> ```
> ✓
> ```

> ```
> INSERT INTO test VALUES(
>
> 'happy sing, rahul bedi, ashish singh, venkat rao'
> );
> ```
>
> ```
> ✓
> ```

> ```
> select  SUBSTRING_INDEX(TRIM(j.name),' ', 1)
> from test t
> join json_table(
>   replace(json_array(t.names), ',', '","'),
>   '$[*]' columns (name varchar(50) path '$')
> ) j
> ```
>
> ```
> | SUBSTRING_INDEX(TRIM(j.name),' ', 1) |
> | :----------------------------------- |
> | happy                                |
> | rahul                                |
> | ashish                               |
> | venkat                               |
> ```

*db<>fiddle [here](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=mysql_8.0&fiddle=488f165c085a5be71296aba212cbd93b)*