# Split Text SQL - Break cells

Tags: sql, mysql

I have the below database and need column "colval" split up. I only need the first set of numbers for each cell. For example '409509200|JNJ|WMD1', I only need column to return '409509200'(aka, need all characters before the first |). See below image...

[image]

Comment: Is it the same problem as [MySQL: select first element of a comma-separated list](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11241492/mysql-select-first-element-of-a-comma-separated-list)?

Comment: similar but no, substring_index is not an option

Comment: Could you please clarify then, what does "split up the column" mean? Do you need to update values in that column so that the result is has the only leftmost part before the bar symbol?

Comment: @Dmitry - Correct. For example, If I have aaaa|bbbb|cccc, I only want to return values aaaa

Comment: *substring_index is not an option* ? Why???

Answer (score 1):

one easy way is to add 0 to the fiel. this convert it to a numeric val and add 0

```
select '409509200|JNJ|WMD1' + 0;
```

or

```
select colval + 0 from yourTable;
```

**sample**

```
mysql> select '409509200|JNJ|WMD1' + 0;
+--------------------------+
| '409509200|JNJ|WMD1' + 0 |
+--------------------------+
|                409509200 |
+--------------------------+
1 row in set, 1 warning (0.00 sec)

mysql>
```

Comment: I love the brevity of this convert, you just have to add nothing and you are good.